# MVC 5 - Default radio button to nothing selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

I have a "div" with id="SendMeCatalog" which only displays on the page when the user selects to buy a product that has Catalog available. Hidding/showing the div is controlled by JavaScript. The reason is because some product doesn't have Catalog available and if the user selects a product that doesn't have catalog available then the div with id="SendMeCatalog" will be hidden on the page.

Now, I have a Model that has a required property called SendThemCatalog and it is set to boolean with null-able. The reason is because I want to default the radio button to have nothing selected.

```
[Required]    
public bool? SendThemCatalog {get; set; }
```

Note, I used [Required] because I want to use Html.ValidatoinMessageFor(...) to ensure that a Yes/No is selected. By default, nothing is selected.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.SendThemCatalog, "Please select Yes/No")
```

Now, my problem is that, when the user selects a product that doesn't have Catalog available -> which means the div with id="SendMeCatalog" will be hidden -> then I have a ModelState invalid error when the user submit a httppost request. The error is related to the SendThemCatalog property.

What do I have to do to overcome this problem? How can I ensure that the SendThemCatalog is set to False when the user selects a product that doesn't have Catalog available?

Thanks

Comment: do you use client side validation?

Comment: for client side, I only have 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SendThemCatalog, "Please select Yes/No")

Comment: I guess you dont use client side validation then you can use ModelState.Remove method by checking if product has no catolog available with your custom method

Comment: can you please tell me more about why you think I should use the ModelState.Remove method in this case? I've tested it and it works; but I would like to understand why I should use it and when should I not be using it. Thanks

Comment: You can use this method for special conditions to omit validaiton for one of your model field and in this case if your models has relation with eachother you can change condition part like checking product's catalog count

Comment: Dont use it this Method for strongly specified validations. But in this case your fied is nullable so you can use this :)

Comment: so which method should i use now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146552/discussion-between-hasan-and-cb4).

Comment: You need a conditional validation attribute. Consider a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` attribute, or you can easily write your own - refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @hasan I followed your answer and it works. But, I am not sure if should I do it this way. I don't know if it will cause any drawback for me. Idea?

Comment: @CB4 You can use ModelState.Remove when you want to omit nullable fields according to situations, I can't see any drawback here

Comment: @hasan Thank you very much for your help. Really appreciated. I am still hesitating to mark it as answer though. I don't know if it will cause me any problem later on.

Comment: Your welcome :) you can search modelstate.remove usages

Answer (score 1):

In server side you can omit model validation error according to your specific condition by creating your custom `HasCatalog(int ProductId)` method and using `ModelState.Remove` method.

If your models has relation with eachothers you can also check Product Catolog count instead of using `HasCatalog(int ProductId)`

There is a example about `ModelState.Remove`

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(YourModel model)
    {   
        if(!HasCatalog(model.ProductId))   // add your condition here
           ModelState.Remove("SendThemCatalog"); // to omit SendThemCatalog Validation Error

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Do some stuff, eventually redirect elsewhere
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: This puts business logic in the controller, which isn't a best practice.

Comment: @Tsahi Asher please tell me why you think this is not a "best practice"? thanks

Comment: condition part can be change if your Product and Catalog models has a relation

Comment: @CB4 input validation is the first step of your business logic, and should be handled by your business objects. The job of the controller is to translate data to and from the view, not validate input.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CustomValidationAttribute`, like so:

First, create a validation method, who's signature is predefined by the `CustomValidationAttribute` API ([see the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.method(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that there is an error in the return value. It should be `ValidationResult`, not `bool`). For example,

```
public static ValidationResult ValidateSendThemCatalog(bool? value, ValidationContext context)
{
    ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.Success;
    YourModel yourModel = context.ObjectInstance as YourModel;
    if (yourModel.HasCatalog && value == null)
    {
        result = new ValidationResult($"{context.DisplayName} is required.");
    }
    return result;
}
```

I.e, any `ValidationResult` which is different from `ValidationResult.Success` (which is `null`) will trigger a validation error.

Next, decorate your property with a `[CustomValidation]` attribute:

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(YourModel), nameof(ValidateSendThemCatalog))]
public bool? SendThemCatalog { get; set; }
```

Comment: How/where does the validation method go?

Comment: @CB4 typically in your model. The point is that the model also contains the validation logic. the parameters of the `[CustomValidation]` point to the type where the method is located, and the method's name (If you are using a Visual Studio earlier than 2015, you can just specify the name as a string).